# Get all websocket messages in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, protractor, webdriver-io

I have a react project wherein I communicate to a websocket and based on the message, I do something. I sometimes update the UI or just do not do anything.

When I am writing e2e tests, I am able to test the components in UI like this:

```
When(/^I update the list "(\d+)"$/, (listNumber) => {
  const elements = browser.$$('div.list_id')[listNumber];
  browser.call(() => (
    // I make the websocket call based on the listNumber to update the list
  ));
});
```

That works well.

My question is I want to have a method which is relevant to e2e testing which tracks all the websocket messages from the client.
I do have a custom polling logic which tracks for changes in the UI but I cannot use it in this case.

For example : Consider the following messages from websocket

```
{"adding_item":"ListItem 1 with id 123"}
{"adding_item":"ListItem 2 with id 345"}
{"bonus_item":"BonusItem 1 with id 1"}
{"adding_item":"ListItem 3 with id 124"}
```

For all the `adding_item` messages I change UI but for `bonus_item` I change nothing in the UI!   How do I detect `bonus_item` has been received from the websocket in the e2e test?

npm command I run :
`"automation": "node node_modules/webdriverio/bin/wdio --host=localhost --baseUrl=http://localhost:9000 automation/wdio.conf.js"`

Few things:
I do not want to change the server/websocket logic.
I do not want to change anything but e2e stuff. Meaning I do not want to change the actual app.

Answer (score 1):

To intercept WebSocket messages, you must install devtools (https://webdriver.io/docs/devtools-service.html - Note that this only works with Chrome browser).
After installing you'll be able to intercept websocket frames using Chrome DevTools Protocol (https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#type-WebSocketFrame).

```
browser.cdp('Network', 'enable');
browser.on('Network.webSocketFrameReceived', (params) => {
    console.log(params.response.payloadData);
};
```

Also note that you must activate devtools in your wdio-conf.js:

```
export.config = {
    // ...
    services: ['devtools'],
    // ...
};
```

Hope this helps.